# Regex Help on finding string with non repeating highlighter

Tags: reactjs, regex

I am trying to write Regex expression & not able to figure out how to stop repeating char.

```
Input String : 0.000000
Search String : 000
Output String highlighting : 0.**000**000  -> First match with extact length & ignore rest
```

> Tried below expression in javascript :

```
/000/
Its giving 0.**000000**
```

> Example in editor :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highlighter-with-emotion-forked-614pp?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: dot is not mandatory & this expression is not working

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would help to describe how you you've tried. You say you tried to use the regex `/000/`, but don't show us what your attempt is. You do link to a codesandbox, but all relevant code should be in the question.

Comment: I am afraid `react-highlighter` is so written that it highligts all matches. See https://github.com/helior/react-highlighter/blob/9c59bfe8a19bc8df1fa02cb2298a94a6bbb13b3f/lib/highlighter.js#L196.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind based regex to only match the first `000` (tested in the OP sandbox and confirmed it's working):

```
<Highlighter search={/(?<=^\d*\.)000/}>0.000000</Highlighter>
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/PWGzrD/1):

[image]

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      0 or more digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  000                      '000'
```